# Java bounded wilcard type

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I need to define a generic class, and the type parameter must be an enum. I think it should look something like

```
public class <T> MyClass<T extends Enum<T>> {

}
```

But I can't seem to figure out the exact syntax. I should mention that I need a way to refer to the type (within MyClass) that it is instantiated with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyClass<T extends Enum<T>> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the approved answer looks syntactically correct, what's the scenario for such a declaration? Are you trying to write some class that can operate on *any* `enum`-defined type, like [`java.util.EnumSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) or [`java.util.EnumMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)? It's an unusual arrangement, so be sure you really need it in order to meet your requirements.

Comment: This is actually a use case you often have. For example, you could also create a TreeSet of type <T extends Comparable<T>>, meaning a set of things you can compare to each other.

Comment: Yes, that's almost the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, without the derivation. I was asking specifically about the use of Enum here. I took the question to be focused on Enum less than the generalized problem of writing such a generic declaration.